# Android UI programmatically GridLayout position

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, android-gridlayout

I am trying to implement the layout below and the idea is to programming dynamic-UI:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/stlirgv7coqf0eu/mockup1.png.

The JSON I used for the application is as follows:

```
{
"name": "Formulare",
"url": "http://server.save-data.de/13467",
"rows": 5,
"cols": 3,
"formItems": [
    {
        "type": "button",
        "value": "Abschicken",
        "action": "send",
        "posX": 2,
        "posY": 4,
        "width": 2,
        "height": 2
    },
    {
        "type": "label",
        "value": "Vorname",
        "posX": 1,
        "posY": 2,
        "width": 2,
        "height": 2
    },
    {
        "type": "label",
        "value": "Nachname",
        "posX": 1,
        "posY": 3,
        "width": 2,
        "height": 2
    },
    {
        "type": "inputFieldText",
        "value": "Max",
        "validation": "50",
        "placeholder": "Vorname",
        "name": "firstname",
        "localStorage": true,
        "mandatory": true,
        "posX": 2,
        "posY": 2,
        "width": 2,
        "height": 3
    },
    {
        "type": "inputFieldText",
        "value": "Mustermann",
        "validation": "50",
        "placeholder": "Nachname",
        "name": "lastname",
        "localStorage": true,
        "mandatory": true,
        "posX": 2,
        "posY": 3,
        "width": 2,
        "height": 3
    }        
]}
```

I used the mocky http://www.mocky.io/v2/5316e43f2b7484ac02382f7c for the JSON-Data and for JSON-Parser I chosed from FasterXML Jackson -> (github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

To realize the JSON to Java Object works! The Problem is, how can I position the Objects??
I guess GridLayout is suitable for my needs but I dont know how I realize it without XML.

I can only show the Objects in a list, here is the code:

```
ScrollView scrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.formContainer);

GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(getApplicationContext());
layout.setOrientation(GridLayout.VERTICAL);
layout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

List<FormItem> formItems = form.getFormItems();
if (formItems != null) {
    for (FormItem formItem : formItems) {
        layout.addView(formItem.getViewObject(this));
    }
}
scrollView.addView(layout);
```

Comment: You can design a layout item which has a textview/edittext , check box and radiogroup in a linearlayout with horizontal orientation. \n populate this layout for each new entry in your list

Comment: @BlackBeard can you please show me an example code of the LinearLayout, how u mean it?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?? What is the use of your method getViewObject()??

Comment: The items shows actually in a list because List<FormItem> formItems = form.getFormItems(); -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/6jtnom1zyoetqqs/Screenshot_2014-03-17-14-07-28.png 
But I want show the items in position with defining in JSON-Data. The goal is to schow the UI in this form: -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/xzgwfdu80g2lrwg/Screenshot_2014-02-24-15-11-39.png

Comment: The method getViewObject() goes to the Factory-Classes and get the JSON-Data.

Here is a example code of the button:

 public View getViewObject(DynamicForm form){
  Button dfbutton = new Button(form);
  dfbutton.setText(this.getValue());
  dfbutton.setWidth(this.getWidth());
  dfbutton.setHeight(this.getHeight());
  dfbutton.setX(this.getPosX());
  dfbutton.setY(this.getPosY());
  
  return dfbutton;
 }

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is define gridview in layout XML

```
<GridView
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="5dp" />
```

Then create a grid item.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:soundEffectsEnabled="true" >

<com.rizem.cbehindcode.grid.SquareImageView
    android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<TextView
    android:background="#55000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hapticFeedbackEnabled="true"
    android:id="@+id/titeText"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp"
    android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSearchResultTitle" />
```

Now Create custom Adapter by extending BaseAdapter class.

```
 public class IndexAdapter2 extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private Context context;
        private boolean selected = false;

        public IndexAdapter2(Context context) {
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            this.context = context;
                //TODO :Parse your json and add item according to it
                // in my case i am adding only textview and image view you can add other
                //Controls also .

            items.add(new Item("Chapter 1 ", R.drawable.background1));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 2 ", R.drawable.background2));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 3 ", R.drawable.background3));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 4 ", R.drawable.background4));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 5", R.drawable.background5));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 6", R.drawable.background6));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 7", R.drawable.background7));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 8", R.drawable.background8));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 9", R.drawable.background9));
            items.add(new Item("Chapter 10", R.drawable.background10));

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return items.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return items.get(i);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return items.get(i).drawableId;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            View v = view;
            ImageView picture;
            TextView name;

            if (v == null) {
                         //Inflate your custom gird item list. and set the controls data
                v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, viewGroup, false);
                v.setTag(R.id.picture, v.findViewById(R.id.picture));
                v.setTag(R.id.titeText, v.findViewById(R.id.titeText));

            }

            picture = (ImageView) v.getTag(R.id.picture);
            name = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.titeText);
            name.setTypeface(Typeface.DEFAULT_BOLD);
            name.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            name.setTextSize(15);

            Item item = (Item) getItem(i);

            picture.setImageResource(item.drawableId);
            name.setText(item.name);
            v.setTag(i);
            return v;
        }

        private class Item {
            final String name;
            final int drawableId;

            Item(String name, int drawableId) {
                this.name = name;
                this.drawableId = drawableId;
            }
        }
    }
```

No in my case i am showing 2 image view with text box side by side so i create a custom image view class to adjust the image dimension which is use in grid item list.xml

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

public SquareImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

}

public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

}
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth()); //Snap to width
}
```

}

Now in your activity

```
//Get the grid layout object.
GridView app_gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);

// Instance of IndexAdapter Class.
app_gridView.setAdapter(new IndexAdapter2(this));
```

Comment: Thank you @RizN81 for you fast answer! I will be test it but the problem is, that I don't wanna to use XML. I want to create dynamic UI programmatically. It means that I parse the JSON-Data to JSON-Object and show with the informations from the JSON the Android-UI.
Please see the comments that I made above. So the form should look like.

Comment: Will then i think you should do some try&error with xml part. What i should suggest you to create custom grid view class by extending it and then create custom grid item class.

Answer (score 0):

Use this as an item for every entry from your json, but control which view will be visible

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="data"
        android:textAlignment="gravity" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/checkboxGrp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/checkbox2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGrp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <!-- add as many radio buttons as possible -->

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </RadioGroup>

</LinearLayout>`
```

Add this view to your scrollviews container

```
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(layout_resource, null);
```

EX: From row 2 from the snapshot only input field is visible. so set others gone

`findViewById(checkboxGrp).setVisibility(View.GONE)` 
`findViewById(radioGrp).setVisibility(View.GONE)`

to disable these groups visibility

This may not be a complete layout, just play around till you get it right
My suggestion go for a listview rather than scrollview if there are many items to display